# How to list all parent categories

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I'm trying to get all parent categories except root category from the collections returned using `Mage::getModel('catalog/category');`

My code :

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');    
    $_categories = $_category
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'));

    foreach ($_categories as $_category){
        print_r($_category);
        die(0);
        echo $_category->getName().'<>';
```

}

**Output is** :

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object (
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category 
    [_eventObject:protected] => category 
    [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category 
    [_useFlatResource:protected] => 
    [_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array (
        [0] => custom_design 
        [1] => custom_design_from 
        [2] => custom_design_to 
        [3] => page_layout 
        [4] => custom_layout_update 
        [5] => custom_apply_to_products
    ) 
    [_treeModel:protected] => 
    [_defaultValues:protected] => Array () 
    [_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array () 
    [_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array () 
    [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1 
    [_isReadonly:protected] => 
    [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category 
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_collection 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array (
        [entity_id] => 1 
        [entity_type_id] => 3 
        [attribute_set_id] => 0 
        [parent_id] => 0 
        [created_at] => 2013-09-14 12:39:35 
        [updated_at] => 2013-09-14 12:39:35 
        [path] => 1 
        [position] => 0 
        [level] => 0 
        [children_count] => 45 
        [name] => Root Catalog
    ) 
    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 
    [_origData:protected] => Array (
        [entity_id] => 1 
        [entity_type_id] => 3 
        [attribute_set_id] => 0 
        [parent_id] => 0 
        [created_at] => 2013-09-14 12:39:35 
        [updated_at] => 2013-09-14 12:39:35 
        [path] => 1 
        [position] => 0 
        [level] => 0 
        [children_count] => 45 
        [name] => Root Catalog
    ) 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array () 
    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ()
)
```

May be I need to add an extra attribute for this? Any other idea please share

Comment: what do you mean by "all parent categories"? All categories that have children? all categories on the first level? all parent categories of a specific category?

Comment: @Marius All categories on the first level.. :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should get you the first level categories

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want only active categories
;
```

Comment: Great.. I never thought about `addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)` magic filter. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are asking for all the 'Top Level' categories here? thus the children of the root category only, and not their children?

You can use the category TreeModel to get this done (or to get to categories, using a categoryID as the starting (top level node)

As an example to get you started:

```
$treeModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getTreeModel()->loadNode($topLevelCatId);
$nodes = $treeModel->loadChildren()->getChildren();
```

If you are looking for only categories that have child categories, the same code can be used, but you need to iterate $nodes, and check for existence of child categories.

Comment: How to get the name of category from node object ? Debugged it, couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

For the people looking for MySQL query to fetch all Magento categories.

```
SELECT
    e.entity_id AS id,
    e.parent_id,
    e.path,
    e.`level`,

IF (
    at_name.value_id > 0,
    at_name.
VALUE
    ,
    at_name_default.
VALUE

) AS `name`
FROM
    `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (
    `at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`
)
AND (
    `at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '41'
)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (
    `at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`
)
AND (
    `at_name`.`attribute_id` = '41'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only top level, than you can go with:

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
foreach($_categories as $_category)
  {
   echo $_category->getName();
 }
```